# 'Capital' vs 'funding' vs 'money' (for producing TV/movies)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is the term 'capital' appropriate to describe the money a production company provides to TV show producers to produce a movie or series?

Or are the terms 'money' or 'funding' have a better fit?

For example, which is most appropriate in:

> The new scifi movie had reduced capital/funding/money when the studio changed directors.

Comment: **capital** - *wealth in the form of money or other assets owned by a person or organization or **available for a purpose such as starting a company or investing (or producing a movie)***.

Comment: Let me give you the sentence. TV show capital hasn't opened up for new ideas yet. Can this mean the money that is available for making TV shows.

Comment: We usually talk about *opening up **to** new ideas*, but other than that - sure.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.